# Android web view not displaying https:\\ url 

Tags: android, webview

I have used web view to display html data. Now html data contains image , with src=\"Title : Android web view not displaying https:\ url .
hview does not support for https url .
If suppose i used with http then it works fine .
IS there any solution ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: So when you use http it works fine though right? And what exactly happens. Does it simply show nothing (it's blank)?

Answer (score 12):

[Click here](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/) to get the solution

Use the follwoing code. You can open https using the following code

```
WebView webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
 public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
 handler.proceed() ;
 }
}
```

Donot forget to vote if my response is helpful for you.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: SslErrorHandler cannot be resolved to a type, SslErrorHandler cannot be resolved to a type